# How do we set background image of TextBlock in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am facing problem in setting the background of textblock in Windows Phone.

```
<TextBlock Text="Forget Password" Height="19" Width="156">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="MyImage.jpg" />
 </Grid.Background>
 <TextBlock Text="Forget Password" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 6):

The TextBlock element cannot display a background image. You can display an image behind your TextBlock as follows:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="..."/>
    <TextBlock Text="Forget Password" Height="19" Width="156">
</Grid>
```

You might have to apply a suitable Margin or padding to your image for this to work.

If you want to add images to a number of TextBlocks, you might want to consider re-templating yor TextBlock via a Style.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a border control to contain the `TextBlock`:-

```
<Border Background="{StaticResource KeyToDesiredBackgroundBrush}">
   <TextBlock Text="Forget Password" Height="19" Width="156" />
</Border>
```

Comment: @user388088: can you be more specific? Are you sure you've made the TextBlock big enough to hold all the text? Are you sure you don't want to be using the `MidWidth` property instead of `Width`?

Comment: this is my xaml <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <PasswordBox Width="296" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Forget Password" Height="39" Width="156">
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>