# WP7 - simplest code to set inputfocus TextBox background, foreground

Tags: windows-phone-7

In Windows Phone 7, I'm looking for simple code to set the background and foreground for a TextBox with inputfocus.

I'm doing this in order to comply with the different themes, and my application visually uses background canvases and other controls which need a standard colorset for controls.

NOTE: Regular foreground, background and borderbrush are fine, and set easily:

```
<TextBox Background="#BFFFFFFF" BorderBrush="#BFFFFFFF" Foreground="Black" 
Canvas.Left="297" Canvas.Top="392" FontSize="20" Height="63" Name="textBox8" 
Text="10" Width="126" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do we set background image of TextBlock in Windows Phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779816/how-do-we-set-background-image-of-textblock-in-windows-phone)

Comment: The question wasn't a duplicate, but there was an answer there that solved it.  I will post the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a similar but slightly different question here on SO, I found a solution, using a Border:

```
<Border Background="{StaticResource KeyToDesiredBackgroundBrush}">
   <TextBlock Text="Forget Password" Height="19" Width="156" />
</Border>
```

My specific solution ended up being the following:

```
   <TextBlock Canvas.Left="73" Canvas.Top="405" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Height="30" Name="textInflationLabel" Text="Gasoline Inflation (%):" TextAlignment="Right" Width="224" />
   <Border Name="BorderInflation" Background="#BFFFFFFF" Height="45" Width="104" Canvas.Left="308" Canvas.Top="395">
         <TextBox Background="#BFFFFFFF" BorderBrush="#BFFFFFFF" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" Margin="-10,-10,0,0" Height="64" Width="125" Name="tbInflation" Text="12" />
   </Border>
```

Frankly, this seems a little hokey.  Hopefully in the future, there are simpler ways to perform such standard tasks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the appearance of a control in different states, then you should modify the Style for that control and change the values by using the `VisualStateManager` as illustrated in the answer to this question: [Windows Phone 7 (WP7) Change a button's background color on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476963/windows-phone-7-wp7-change-a-buttons-background-color-on-click)