# Display text over image

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need to create a Grid with 3 columns where each of cell has a textblock over an image.

I saw this code [How do we set background image of TextBlock in Windows Phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779816/how-do-we-set-background-image-of-textblock-in-windows-phone) but will I need to add a new grid for each cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to add a new grid for each cell. You can just add an  control to the cell and then a . It will render the text over the image in each cell. Just set the Grid.Column="" for  the image and textblock.